# Why GPU takes longer time to process first frame of video than CPU in Caffe?

Tags: gpu, cpu, caffe

I tried to run the code of [SegNet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/SegNet-Tutorial/blob/master/Scripts/webcam_demo.py) web demo. When I use

```
caffe.set_mode_cpu()
```

the average frame rate is about 9 second per frame.

However, when I use

```
caffe.set_mode_gpu()
```

it takes about **107s** to process the first frame and about **5 frames per second** starting from the second frame.

Why it takes longer time using GPU than using CPU when it processes first frame? Is there any way to improve the frame rate while processing the first frame?

Thank you!!!! Really need help.

Comment: Wow, that is really interesting. Nothing in the code looks like it's doing extra buffering, so it's got to be something about Caffe. Have you tried it on a different CPU/GPU combination?

Comment: @bright-star Thanks for your response. No I don't have any other CPU/GPU combination....

Comment: What is your GPU and CUDA versions?

Comment: I suspect it's probably the driver context and shader/kernel ptx being constructed that is taking up the time. If you are on NVidia, you can enable shader caching which may affect the bootup time. In some cases, the driver will recompile the GPU kernel code first. Also, OpenGL is known for taking extravagant amounts of time to startup, this has nothing to do with any kind of processing that comes afterwards.